# Can't upload specific files with PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I have recently came across a problem which I've never ever experienced!

I've basically created a form like this:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

After that I added a really simple PHP script, just for testing:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo 'OK';
} else {echo 'empty';}

?>
```

My settings in WAMP is that the file cannot be more than 2MB. Alright, so now if I upload an image or music or .exe or whatever file, it does shows the "OK" text. Even if it exceeds the file limit.

However when I upload a .zip file which exceeds the limit, it actually shows the "empty" message to me, so basically the form didn't submit, but the page reloaded.

So can anyone please tell me what is going on here? Because I don't really know what could be the issue here.

Comment: Try checking for $_FILES['file'] instead of $_POST['submit']

Comment: What do you exactly mean? It outputs: "empty" - because it thinks that the form isn't submitted.

Comment: it sounds like some file extension.. almost as if your default ini is not allowing *.zip

Comment: try this as a debug meth : 
if ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/zip")
echo "This is a zip file and its OK";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how, but I've found the answer.

The POST maximum size is actually more than 8MB. My zip files were much bigger and my music or exe files were not that big.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: That makes sense.. Might i suggest you add some catch on it.. so if you are uploading, you move the file, if the file doesn't move, throw exception. Will make your life easier! :}

Comment: And dont be afraid to limit the filetype allowed in upload.. im sure you know all this! ;]